# With that or without that

Tags: conjunctions

I think the following sentence is correct both ways with **that** and without **that**

> The smell of cooking told them **(that)** there was a meal in the offing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Omitting 'that' in this sentence](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/126806/omitting-that-in-this-sentence)

Comment: What is your question?